# Financial returns for nothing or anything

Tags: ambiguity

*You owe me nothing in return* vs. *you don't owe me anything in return*

Could there be a difference in meaning between those?

That is, might the first sentence have the cunning sense of "since I was there for you, you borrowed much and gave nothing back. You therefore owe such nothing."

"Bank lent something, which you took; nothing paid, yet. Nothing in return to the bank, nothing the bank charged, with interest."

So, between asking the linguist or the accountant.

Comment: I can't think of any context where ***[verb] + "nothing"*** has a well-established meaning that's different to ***"not" + [verb + "anything"***, but I stand to be corrected on that point. Certainly there's no such difference in the example here - so whatever you're thinking about that, *you are mistaken*.

Comment: The sentence versions with "anything" and "nothing" are generally equivalent, but there may be subte differences that are perceived subsconsciously by native speakers. I don't feel qualified to write an answer about it, but it is well worth the try by someone more versed in these matters.

Answer (score 2):

> That is, might the first sentence have the cunning sense of "since I was there for you, you borrowed much and gave nothing back. You therefore owe such nothing."

No, it could not have that sense. If you borrow money and don't pay the lender back, you still owe them the money; there's no sense in which you could be said to owe them nothing.

Comment: What if the currency is emotional support and the bank is Alanis Morissette?

Comment: I interpreted "I was there for you" as "I helped you out with money." If you mean emotional support: you don't *borrow* emotional support, so you would both "owe nothing" and "not owe anything," the two being synonymous.

Comment: It is true that "I owe you nothing" can be a way of showing ingratitude, but "I don't owe you anything" can have the same meaning.

Comment: For the specific context, song verses about an apparently unconditional love in this relationship, yet to a point of displaying an unilateral loan resort at times. That's why the statement (owe "nothing") instead of "not owing" seemed curious. And fair, I might say haha

Comment: While Morissette's line offers *I owe you nothing* without sarcasm, irony could be read into anything. The lyrics can also read as "ripped from a therapy session".

Comment: When _why-is-there-something-rather-than-nothing_ lands on the balance of payments, things go quantum physics

Comment: I think "I don't owe you anything" has the same connotations; it just appears less often in song lyrics because it has more syllables and is less nice metrically.